# What am I doing wrong with the images on my page?

Tags: html, css, image, background, header

```css
body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}


.main-nav {
 display: none;
 font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
 position: absolute;
 top: 70;
 left: 15;
 font-size: .5em;
}

.promo {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 99;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: .7em;
 text-align: center;
}


.welcome {
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 background: 
 linear-gradient(#303030, transparent 90%),
 url('../imgs/camerabg.jpg') no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: -10px;
 padding: 200px;
} 

.welcome h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
}

.welcome a {
 text-decoration-style: underline;
 color: lightgrey;
 font-size: 2em;
 display: inline-block;
}

.welcome ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

.location {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 2px solid lightgrey;
 color: lightgrey;
}

.products {
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 height: 150px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
 background: linear-gradient(#181818, transparent 90%),
 url('../imgs/oldcamera.jpg') no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 150px;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}

 .products h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
 }

 .products a {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 2em;
 }

 /*===============================
    Intro
==============================*/

.intro1, .intro2 p {
 font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
}

.intro1, .intro2 span {
 font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Yantramanav" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/stylesheet.css">
 <title>TITLE HERE</title>
</head>

<body>

<header>
<div class="promo">
 <p>BUY 1 GET 1 Free 1/2 OFF CLOCK FRAME COMBOS<br>
 *Offer Valid 5/1/18. May not be combined with another offer or promotion. While supplies last.*<p>
</div>

<div class="logo">
<h1> Name Here</h1>
</div>

<div class="main-nav">
 <ul>
  <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>Blog</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li> Hire Us</li></a>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="welcome">
 <h1>Welcome To Our New Site</h1>
 <p>Let us help you with your best moments.</p>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Order Now</a></li>
 <li><a class="location" href="#">Find Our New Location</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</header>

<div class="intro1">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
<span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</span>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I'm working on a project and I *just* *can't* get things to center.

The header image is making the page scroll horizontally, the text isn't centered on the header, the same thing happens with another image later on the page, and on mobile the images aren't filling the entire viewport, everything is over to the left side of the viewport.

**I've gotten the meta tag to make the viewport responsive.**

HTML:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Yantramanav" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/stylesheet.css">
<title>Title</title>
```

I've hidden the overflow property on the header to try to help this, but that didn't solve my issues.

**Both images sizes are 640 x 480 pixels**

CSS for width and margins to be reset:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

html {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Here's my CSS for the navigation, header (including background image), title, logo, and an advertisement at the very top of the page.

```
.main-nav {
display: none;
font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
position: absolute;
top: 70;
left: 15;
font-size: .5em;
}

.promo {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 99;
padding: 10px;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
font-size: .7em;
text-align: center;
}


.welcome {
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
background-color: lightgrey;
background: 
linear-gradient(#303030, transparent 90%),
url('../imgs/camerabg.jpg') no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin-top: -10px;
padding: 200px;
border: 2px red solid;
} 

.welcome h1 {
font-size: 2em;
}

.welcome a {
text-decoration-style: underline;
color: lightgrey;
font-size: 2em;
display: inline-block;
}

.welcome ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

.location {
font-size: 1.5em;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 10px;
border: 2px solid lightgrey;
color: lightgrey;
}
```

Here's CSS for an image later in the page:

```
.products {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
height: 150px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000;
background: linear-gradient(#181818, transparent 90%),
url('../imgs/oldcamera.jpg') no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
padding: 150px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.products h1 {
font-size: 3em;
 }

.products a {
padding: 10px;
border: 2px solid lightgrey;
color: lightgrey;
font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You've worked hard to ask a good question, thank you. I'm going to suggest that to get more / quality answers, you should make a fiddle, or a working snippet, that demonstrates the problem.  [How to Add a Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: As a total aside: I've had some pretty hard-to-troubleshoot bugs in sites due to this very rule you've included: `* {box-sizing: border-box;
}` - I would recommend NOT putting styles on the `*` selector like that, especially box-sizing :)

Comment: Thank you, I added a snippet to help show what I'm having issues with. That's interesting about the border-box property, I read that it's a good idea to include so you won't have margin/padding issues. Thanks for the heads up. I took it out and it did make things somewhat better to line up.